# Why does 0.125, formatted with 2 digits of decimal precision, show "0.12" not "0.13"?

Tags: c++, floating-point, string-formatting

Consider:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
 
int main()
{
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2);
    std::cout << 0.125 << '\n'; // Prints "0.12"
    std::cout << 0.126 << '\n'; // Prints "0.13" as expected
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/K4xeK8ns4)

I know that floating point math isn't perfectly precise, but isn't `0.125` one of the values that actually is represented exactly? Why does it round down to `"0.12"` instead of up to `"0.13"` when formatting it?

Comment: Does 0.12500001 work?

Comment: For what it's worth, rounding "half to even" [looks like this](https://godbolt.org/z/cY85Ynoc7).  It's a rounding method that doesn't bias toward 0 or infinity.

Comment: @DrewDormann most people only know about the rounding they learned in elementary school, but https://xkcd.com/1053/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, `0.125` is one of the rare floating point values that should have an exact binary representation.

Your rounding mode is probably set to [round-half-to-even](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even).

Comment: Evidently! Will mark as accepted once it lets me.